# Postgres Sorting Optimisation

Tags: postgresql, database-design, postgresql-9.4

I am looking for a way to order table entries during insertion rather than fetching.
If this is not possible, is there a way to have an auto-increment respective to the primary key? (i.e. if `id` is primary, `ai` will increment starting from 0 for every different `id` inserted)

example:

```
id | ai
---+---
 0 | 0
 0 | 1
 0 | 2
 1 | 0
 1 | 1
 1 | 2
 1 | 3
```

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by “order table entries during insertion”? Also, the word for “table entry” is “row”.

Comment: What do you mean by "starting from zero for every inserted Id"? if id is the primary key it will be another one for each row? You need to explain your problem a bit better and maybe add an example

Comment: I have added an example demonstrating the behaviour I'm trying to replicate.

Comment: How is id a primary key in that sample data?

Comment: I realised how my question was fairly unintuitive, however one of the answers sufficed. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: No, and yes, respectively.

SQL databases do store data in some sort of order; whether by allocation, or (when there is a clustered index on a table) by the clustering key.

However, the process of executing a query does not guarantee that the data will be returned in the order in which is was stored. To guarantee the order of your data, you must use the `ORDER BY` clause in your `SELECT` statement.

Yes, you can create an auto-incrementing ID value in PostgreSQL. While this would normally be used to create a *surrogate key* to be used as the primary key, it appears it can be used to merely create a unique column, if you like.

[The accepted answer to this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/1287/116653) should give you what you need. You either use a sequence, or the `SERIAL` pseudo-datatype (which creates a sequence for you behind the scenes). Check the docs for your version for more details on sequences.

(I believe `SERIAL` will most likely start from 1, not 0 - you would probably have to set up the sequence yourself to get a specific starting point)

Note: This answer is for the tagged version of PostgreSQL, 9.4. As of version 10, PostgreSQL now has an [identity column](https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-10-identity-columns/) mechanism similar to that in Oracle or DB2, per the SQL:2003 & SQL:2008 standard (feature # T174). See the doc for `GENERATED ... FOR IDENTITY` [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html).

Comment: `SERIAL` is now supplanted by the *identity column* feature as of Postgres 10. See [this article](https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-10-identity-columns/) at 2nd Quadrant. See the [doc for `GENERATED … FOR IDENTITY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html).

Comment: @BasilBourque I'd initially left this out (the OP specified PostgreSQL 10), but have now added it the info in your comment for completeness. Thank you.

Comment: For more about identity column, see also my [lengthy Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44982117/642706) to a similar Question. And the first part of [my slideshow](https://speakerdeck.com/basilbourque/10-in-10-ten-new-things-in-postgres-10) on 10 new things in Postgres 10.

Comment: I don't think they want a simple auto increment column.